# Drupal 9.2.9 - Conditional field in inline_entity_form (#states) not working

Tags: drupal, state, drupal-8, drupal-9

I have entity "parking_lot" with several "pricings", in the "parking_lot" entity form, there is a field "pricings" using the widget inline_entity_form_complex. In the parking_lot form I set conditional fields with the #states API (to display fields only sometimes swith a boolean field). The #states works but only in the original form of a "pricing" entity, but when I edit a pricing from the parking_lot entity, the #states doesn't works. How to set #states in a inline_entity_form_complex field widget ? The states work in normal field, but in the widget it do not works.
This is my code. Please look the Gif #1 (working) and the Gif #2 (not working).

A created a hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() :

```
$form['field_level_time_unit']['#states'] = [
    'invisible' => [
      'input[name="field_level_pricing_mode"]' => ['value' => 0],
    ]
  ];

  $form['field_level_price']['#states'] = [
    'invisible' => [
      'input[name="field_level_pricing_mode"]' => ['value' => 0],
    ]
  ];

  $form['field_level_of_reference']['#states'] = [
    'visible' => [
      'input[name="field_level_pricing_mode"]' => ['value' => 0],
    ]
  ];
```

The #states is working here:
[image: The #states is working here]

The #states is not working with the widget inline_entity_form_complex :
[image: The #states is not working with the widget inline_entity_form_complex]

Comment: In which hook did you put the code ?

Comment: I add the info in the issue. In hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().

Comment: Ok, I think it's the issue: this hook catches only the 1st form, the 2nd one has another form_id.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution ! In modules/contrib/inline_entity_form/inline_entity_form.api.php there is several hooks. I used hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter. I adapted the field name with the name updated by the widget, and works normally !

[image]